# How to adjust the width in table using \cline command?

Tags: longtable, width, cline

[image: Here is my code]I would like to create a table with specific horizontal line width,  when I use `\cline` and merge columns in this table , it's OK, but when I fill color to the merged cell, the horizontal line disappeared,how could I fix it?

before coloring:

[image]

after coloring:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 5 columns, and the hidden `\cline` should be  for columns `2-4`.  If that is correct, the solution uses the `hhline` package, with this syntax (replace the black color with the real color of your lines):

```
\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|---|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
```

Normally we should have `\hhline{~|---|~}`, where the symbol `~` used in the description means  ‘*no rule in this column*’. However, as  it is followed by a rule in the following columns, and as it is in a coloured cell, you'll have a white segment. So the trick consists in having for that column a segment of the same colour as the column. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I have 6 columns , and the hidden \cline should be for columns 2-5, how do I modify my code, I don't understand the use of \hhline, I try this command but it just not ok

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have solved the problem